# Moriarty's calculator: some bizarre and deceptive graphical anomalies

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, recreational-mathematics, graphing-functions

**Background:** This is a problem I first came across a few years ago in a calculus textbook (a James Stewart one), where it addressed some of the pitfalls of using graphing calculators. The original context addressed issues with the TI-83 calculator, but seeing as that most people use the vaunted TI-89 nowadays, I thought I would consider some issues with that one. My first few considerations proved to be simple to handle (and I will outline them below), but there is one that I have no idea how to address properly. I think it is sufficiently bizarre so as to call the challenge problem Moriarty's Enigma.

**Necessary information:** The [TI-89 Guidebook](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDYQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Feducation.ti.com%2F~%2Fmedia%2F0470DB419F2144349E4032AFE3C0DD7E&ei=vdbeVIuKLoGHgwSemoHwBg&usg=AFQjCNFv05zoH3G5oD49Zu17nIwzHU9qlA&bvm=bv.85970519,d.eXY) gives information on how the calculator draws objects given the screen dimensions of the calculator. Screen dimensions for all TI graphing calculators may be found [here](https://epsstore.ti.com/OA_HTML/csksxvm.jsp?nSetId=75349). The relevant information from the guidebook may be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe2hb.png) (link provided so as not to make an already long post even longer).

The main point is that the graphing window is $159$ pixels wide and we want to start with $x=0$ and $x=2\pi$ (the reason for this will become very clear in a moment). Since there are $158$ "gaps" between pixels, the distance between pixels is $\frac{2\pi-0}{158}$. Thus, the $x$-values that the calculator actually plots are $x=0+\frac{2\pi}{158}\cdot n$, where $n=0,1,2,\ldots,158$.

**Elementary, my dear TI-89:** First consider the graph of $y=\sin(161x)$, which is graphed below in `dot` mode on the window $0\leq x\leq 2\pi, -1.5\leq y\leq 1.5$ (this will be the window used in all examples so that my results will be reproducible by other users if desired):

[image]

Now consider when the functions $y=\pm\sin(3x)$ are graphed simultaneously in `square` mode:

[image]

It certainly looks as if $\sin(161x)=\pm\sin(3x)$. This actually makes sense in terms of the pixel information noted earlier: for $y=\sin(161x)$, the actual points plotted by the calculator are $\left(\frac{2\pi}{158}\cdot n,\sin\left(161\cdot\frac{2\pi}{158}\cdot n\right)\right)$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots,158$. But
\begin{align}
\sin\left(161\cdot\frac{2\pi}{158}\cdot n\right) &= \sin\left(158\cdot\frac{2\pi}{158}\cdot n+3\cdot\frac{2\pi}{158}\cdot n\right)\\[1em]
  &= \sin(2\pi n)\cos\left(3\cdot\frac{2\pi}{158}\cdot n\right)+\sin\left(3\cdot\frac{2\pi}{158}\cdot n\right)\cos(2\pi n)\quad\text{[$\sin(\alpha+\beta)$]}\\[1em]
  &= \pm\sin\left(3\cdot\frac{2\pi}{158}\cdot n\right),\qquad n=0,1,\ldots,158
\end{align}
Thus, the $y$-values, and hence the points, plotted for $y=\sin(161x)$ lie on either $y=\sin(3x)$ or $-\sin(3x)$, as confirmed by the previous graph.

The same reasoning can be used to show that all of the $y$-values for $\sin(158x)$ are plotted as zero:

[image]

At this point, I was feeling confident about my ability to understand and detect graphing anomalies for trigonometric functions due to periodicity and the like, but the next function has thus far thwarted my analysis completely.

**Moriarty's Enigma:** Graph $\sin(77x)$ in `line` mode:

[image]

I can deduce how $\pm\sin(2x)$ comes into the mix (similar to the $\sin(161x)$ example), but I cannot see how $\pm\cos(2x)$ fits in. The $y$-values for $\sin(161x)$ seem to be a mixture of $\pm\sin(2x),\pm\cos(2x)$, and an array of different trigonometric functions. Here is the graph when all five functions are plotted simultaneously ($\sin(77x)$ plotted in `line` mode while $\pm\sin(2x),\pm\cos(2x)$ in `square` mode):

[image]

As if that were not weird enough, graph $\sin(77x)$ and $\pm\sin(81x)$ in `line` mode:

[image]

Finally, graph $\sin(77x)$ and $\cos(77x)$ in `line` mode:

[image]

What other functions might be hidden in $\sin(77x)$ when graphing on the window $0\leq x\leq 2\pi, -1.5\leq y\leq 1.5$ for the TI-89? Where do $\pm\cos(2x)$ come into play? What about $\sin\left(\frac{77x}{79}\right)$ [fills in the diamond-looking regions] or $-\sin\left(\frac{77x}{79}\right)$ [runs tangent to / crosses middle max], etc.

Comment: My reaction to the last image was the last image itself... xD

Comment: @AvZ Yeah, I thought that gif summed things up perfectly--like what in the deuce is going on here. Bizarre.

Comment: I had encountered something similar when I plotted an animated plot of $y=\sin(10xt)$ where $t$ is the time. You can add that GIF. It'd illustrate this effect very well.

Comment: @AvZ I really wanted to add the plots as gifs so people could see them being graphed. I mean it's truly weird. I didn't even include some of my other observations simply because of the already ridiculous length of the post. But $\sin(77x)$ is just...confounding.

Comment: This is related to sampling-theory it seems. Ever heard of the [Niquist-Shannon sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)?

Comment: @Raskolnikov No, I can't say that I have. I'll make sure to read up on your link and related material. I find it thoroughly fascinating.

Comment: What happens when you plot $\sin(158x)$ in dot mode? I've been experimenting a bit with my calculator and I figured out it has 126 pixels horizontal res. When I plot $\sin(126x)$ I get a near zero curve. When I plot $\sin(157x)$, I'll get the phenomenon with a $\sin$ curve and a $\cos$ curve which is rather easy to explain because $157 = 126 + 31$ and $31$ is $0.5$ away from being a quarter of $126$.

Comment: I missed your plot of $\sin(158x)$ somehow, never mind.

Comment: See [an animation](http://i.imgur.com/es73dVt.gif) of $\sin\left(q\frac{\pi}{158}n\right)$ for $q=1..158$ and samples at $n=1..158$. There you'll see sort of a "reflection" of the series near the end. Of course it is related to Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem. Various patterns from points appear even at about $q=40$.

Comment: @Ruslan Very interesting. Thanks for the gif! Some really interesting behavior going on there. Certainly looks like the Niquist-Shannon sampling theorem is important here. Maybe someone on MSE who knows about that can chime in (I plan to read up on it sometime this week). Very useful animation though.

Comment: Yes check out the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem and also amplitude modulation can be of interest.

Comment: I think I have almost figured it out. If you do your $\sin(77x)$ in dot mode, you will not get the $\cos$ behaviour. What happens in line mode is that your graphing calculator "interpolates" extra values and it looks like you plotted $\sin(77\pi x/158)$ instead of $\sin(77\pi x/79)$.

Comment: @Ruslan I was curious about what you used to produce your animation. Was it Mathematica or something else?

Comment: @Raskolnikov I just now tried graphing $\sin(77x)$ in `dot` mode, and I actually got the $\pm\cos(2x)$ behavior and the $\pm\sin(2x)$ behavior (just as before). You are using a TI-89 to make your observations right? And the window I included in the main text?

Comment: @crash yes, it's Mathematica.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for the info. Think you might be able to share the notebook on dropbox or something? I'd like to toy around with it if you don't mind. Plotting $\sin(77x)$ in `dot` mode did yield some insight actually--it looks like *only* the four different aforementioned functions are being plotted. The question still remains how to coax out the $\pm\sin(2x)$.

Comment: @crash well, I didn't save it as a notebook because it's a trivial thing. Here's a line you can use to look this in interactive mode inside Mathematica: `Manipulate[Show[Plot[Sin[q \[Pi]/158 n], {n, 1, 158}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], ListPlot[Table[Sin[q \[Pi]/158 n], {n, 1, 158}]]], {q, 1, 158, 1}]`.

Comment: @Ruslan Cool. Thanks. I'm going to try to crank this thing out sometime later tonight. Really been bugging me. Freaking Moriarty!

Comment: @crash, then there's something worng with your initial assumption that the TI-89 plots the $2\pi n/158$ points with $n \in \{0,\ldots,158\}$ . It must mean it plots $\pi n/158$ with $n \in \{0,\ldots,2\cdot158\}$ like Ruslan suggests.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Very interesting observation. Maybe my transition from examining the TI-89 as opposed to the TI-83 is flawed then? Because I know that "assumption" is right for the TI-83. You would think the programming would be consistent for the calculators. That is a very good point though.

Answer (score 6):

Don't actually know how exactly Nyquist-Shannon theorem is related to this, but here's a crackdown of what happens with $\sin\left(77\frac{\pi}{158}n\right)$ for $n=1..158$ (equivalently, $\sin(77x)$ with $x=\frac{\pi n}{158}$):

$$f(n)=\sin\left(77\frac{\pi}{158}n\right)=\sin\left(\left(\frac{79}{158}\pi-\frac{2\pi}{158}\right)n\right)=\\
=\sin\left(\left(\frac\pi2-\frac\pi{79}\right)n\right)=\sin\frac{\pi n}2\cos\frac{\pi n}{79}+\cos\frac{\pi n}2\sin\frac{\pi n}{79}.$$

Now consider 4 cases:

1. $n=1+4k,\,k\in\mathbb Z$, then $f(n)=\cos\frac{\pi n}{79}$
2. $n=2+4k,\,k\in\mathbb Z$, then $f(n)=-\sin\frac{\pi n}{79}$
3. $n=3+4k,\,k\in\mathbb Z$, then $f(n)=-\cos\frac{\pi n}{79}$
4. $n=0+4k,\,k\in\mathbb Z$, then $f(n)=\sin\frac{\pi n}{79}$

This is exactly what you asked about $\pm\sin(2x)$ and $\pm\cos(2x)$ functions inside samples of $\sin(77x)$, where $x=\frac{\pi n}{158}$.